# Orientable necklaces and complements

Tags: combinatorics, oeis, necklace-and-bracelets

I'm trying to understand the OEIS sequence [A059078](https://oeis.org/A059078):

> Number of orientable necklaces with 2n beads and two colors which when turned over produce their own color complement.
>
> 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 6, 12, 27, 54, ...

I'm able to recreate the exact number of such necklaces for $n=3$, $n=4$, and $n=5$, but when $n=6$, I obtain 13 such necklaces when there should only be 12 (listed below).

```
000001011111
000010101111
000011001111
000100110111
000101010111
000101011101
000101110011
000110100111
001001011011
001010101011
001010101101
001010110011
001011001011
```

Which one of these doesn't satisfy the criteria?

I consider two strings $s_1$ and $s_2$ equivalent if $min(L(s_1), L(s_1^*)) = min(L(s_2), L(s_2^*))$, where $L(s)$ is the Lyndon word of string $s$ and $s*$ is the turned over version of $s$, obtained by reversal. Also, I believe "orientable necklace" is the same as a chiral bracelet.

Comment: Indeed, from what I checked (by hand), these seem to be all distinct, chiral and self-similar by color complementation and turning over, I may have missed something.

Comment: I also checked the valid cases (by hand) and also found 13 (same as yours). The odd one out seems to me the last one, due to its symmetry. But this is still as per the criteria, as I understand them. I might be missing something in the criteria.

Comment: I wonder if your results agree with the other related OEIS sequences.

Comment: @Karl, yes, my results for A059076 and A059053 match what appears in OEIS. I think caduk's answer explains the discrepancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem originates in this formula (from OEIS):

$a(n) = $[A059076](https://oeis.org/A059076)$(2n) - 2\times$[A059053](https://oeis.org/A059053)$(2n)$

A059076 is the number of pairs of orientable necklaces and A059053 is the number of chiral pairs of necklaces with $n$ beads and two colors (color complements being equivalent).

Actually, the description of A059053 is misleading, since these are not necessarily pairs, but classes of equivalence, where two orientable necklaces are in the same class of equivalence if we can deduce the other by turning over and/or complementing. Most of these equivalence classes are made of two orientable necklaces, except if one is the color complement of the other (and then, the orientable necklace is alone in its class). (Actually, it is not exactly clear what chiral means in this context, so maybe necklaces that are self-similar by complementation should not be counted in this sequence, but then A059053  is wrong).

Now the error in the formula is quite clear: We should not substract twice the equivalence classes with only one necklace.

For $12$ beads, the only such necklace is `000100111011`, explaining the off-by-one error.

---

A059078 goes like this : 13, 28, 58, 120, 246, 496, 1005... (Can't go much further because I coded a very simple but painfully slow algorithm to make sure results were correct)

Here are the 28 necklaces for $n=7$:

```
00001001101111
00011010100111
00100110011011
00001010101111
00001011110011
00101010101011
00001101001111
00010010110111
00010101011101
00000010111111
00001010111101
00001110001111
00010101110011
00010111000111
00101010110101
00101100101101
00101100110011
00010101010111
00010111001011
00000101011111
00010011011101
00010110010111
00000110011111
00011001100111
00100101011011
00101010101101
00101010110011
00101011001011
```

Comment: Thanks for the analysis, this is interesting! One question: what is meant by "pairs of"? So for example for A059076, do we find all the necklaces that are orientable and then we group them in groups of 2? (so the number of combinations of ALL orientable necklaces taken 2 at a time?). I think I am misunderstanding the definition somehow.

Comment: @tps Yes, for example, 001011 and 001101 are counted only once. The notion of pair here is not ambiguous because the classes of equivalence of necklaces that are similar by turning off will all be of size 2 by definition

Comment: Thanks, these definitions are clear now. But why is 000100111011 the odd one? I think that it is orientable, and if it is turned over then it is not a colour complement of the original. So its equivalence class is made of two orientable necklaces (and it is not alone in its class). As such, it should belong also to A059053, and should be subtracted twice. So why is this an exception?

Comment: I think that necklaces that, when turned over, are a complement of the original should not be counted in A059053. This is in the definition: "i.e., turning the necklace over neither leaves it unchanged nor simply swaps the colors.". As such, I think that subtracting twice is correct. But could there be an error in A059076? It would be interesting to be able to count A059076 for n=12 (which is the case in our problem).

Comment: @tps Sorry, I put the wrong link for A059053, maybe  that's what confused you. If you take the necklaces n1:000101001, n2:100101000, n3:111010110, n4:011010111, then (n1, n2) and (n3,n4) both count as a pair or orientable necklace) in A059053, but (n1, n2, n3, n4) count as one equivalence class in A059053 (made of two orientable necklaces) because n3 is the color complement of n1. However, ( 000100111011, 110111001000) forms one class of A059053 composed of only one orientable necklace, because it is it's self complement, so this class should not be removed twice.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. My results agree with yours, and it makes sense that self-complement identical sequences should not be removed twice. That being said, I have a combinatorial class that empirically follows the A059078 sequence, however I cannot prove it directly. I was hoping to create a bijection to the combinatorial class of A059078, but now I also need to figure our what else A059078 is a counting sequence for...

Comment: @Throckmorton I'm confused by the edit you suggest. In A059076, color complements are not equivalent, only necklaces equivalent by turning over. In the example section of OEIS, for n=7, you see that equivalent necklaces under complementation are counted distinctly. This is why we need to subtract twice A059053 (when not self complement), because A059053 considers complements as equivalent.

Comment: The edit was with respect to A059053. Color complements are equivalent for [A059053](https://oeis.org/A059053). "Number of chiral pairs of necklaces with n beads and two colors (color complements being equivalent); i.e., turning the necklace over neither leaves it unchanged nor simply swaps the colors."